# A flagged post was declined, how do we deal with what may be deemed as "incorrect"?

Tags: discussion, support, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

Hmm okay, I know **moderator's actions are final**, but are we allowed to question their decision?

Case in point is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599603/how-to-output-elementary-streams-with-android-media-recorder/15632069#15632069)

Now, I flagged that as very low quality (Another had already flagged it as NAA), but I decided it was probably low quality. It seems, after moderator review, that the answer remains.

It was declined as the usual:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I mean I know flags are based on *opinions*, but surely the majority of the vote goes towards that answer being very poor quality and verging on not even an answer?

Comment: You come here and discuss it. Which is what you did. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were two flags on that answer. A `Very Low Quality` flag, and a `Not an answer` flag. It's not `VLQ`, but it is also not an answer.

I declined your flag. Here is the answer in its glory:

> As you said the MediaRecorder can not split the ES while recording. If so, could you share your way that how did you derive the ES while recording.

I declined it because at the time I read the answer, it did *look* like an answer.

Looking at it now, it is *part answer* (affirming what the OP already knows), and part question "share your way that how did you derive the ES while recording."

Reading it over again, I don't believe it's a answer, so I'll delete it.

It's not `Very Low Quality`. Had your VLQ flag been the only flag on the answer, I would have declined it.

Very low quality has a specific meaning: The post is so undecipherable that no amount of editing will correct it.

Comment: Thanks George, I was debating between the two types of flag. I think my definition of VLQ wasn't in-keeping with the *actual* definition. I'll be more careful when I use that in future :).

Comment: @mattytommo Even the best of us get tripped up by that one.

Comment: @mattytommo, i am the one who flagged it as NAA, and it turned out "helpful"

Comment: @Raynold You did flag it NAA, but after I had already declined the previous set of flags; you're not the original 'NAA' flagger.

Answer (score 3):

The flag was probably declined because it is *not* a very low quality post. Use those for posts that *do* answer the question, but are neigh unreadable to the point where you have *no idea* how to edit into anything sensible.

This post is perfectly legible and can still be edited to be a more complete answer. I would agree with the Not An Answer flag, but a moderator can only respond to multiple flags with *one* response.

The moderators are treating Very Low Quality flags quite strictly these days, so the choice here was to reject your flag. I am a little surprised it was not at the same time converted to a comment though.

Comment: You're right, a VLQ flag would be declined.

Comment: Yeah, I don't use VLQ often as it can be a bit of a grey area. I was debating between VLQ and NAA, I should have went with the latter :)

Comment: At this point, "very low quality" flags are used incorrectly so often on answers, that I wouldn't mind disabling that option for answers. Too many people flag technically incorrect but coherent answers, or everything they see with a downvote, and the other cases could be handled by "not an answer" or "other" flags just as well.